# Maximum number of Hub navigation nodes?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, navigation, hub-site

I'm building a comprehensive navigation in a hub site. Around 230 total nodes. From my testing I've noticed that the hub nav disappears once you go over around 170 nodes.

If I load the web's TopNavigaitonBar collection and their children

`cc.Web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar`

All the 230 nodes are there. They are also visible on classic pages.

If I remove enough nodes the Hub navigation eventually reappears. I can't find any documentation around number of supported nodes for Hub navigation. Has anyone seen this before?